# Update data in Mongo DB with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I have NodeJS with Express server and MongoDB.

I can get data drom DB via jQuery AJAX with:

`$.get('/api/items/3', function(data)`

But I can't update existing data

```
   $.ajax({
        url: '/api/posts/3',
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'New Title'
    })
```

What could be the problem?
No errors in console. Network shows **PUT   200 OK** and I can see data that I sent.

Thanks

Comment: need to send key/value pairs, all you are sending is a value

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. I'm using variables.'New Title' is actually {title: "New Title"}.

Comment: Well if it's new how is db going to be able to identify it? Need to show more code. there isn't enough here to resolve issue

Comment: may be using session to update title againt session ID

Comment: I used Yeoman Angular-fulstack, and just tried to change angular to jQuery, so all worked fine with angular, and jQuery AJAX should work, as it worked with getting data

Answer (score 0):

Your route might be look like this .. check out the body log on console

```
app.put('/api/:item/:id', function(req,res){
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)
.....
})
```